# How to make application file permission with Java client server

Tags: java, client-server

i would make an application client server with java to change or modify the file permission in a folder . 
i had looking for about these information, but i'm still confused with it,i can't find the answer.
what the first thing i do to make this application?

thanks for your advice.

nb : sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [Java remote method invocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) and

see [Security Policies - File Permissions](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csneal/InternetComputing/RM3.html)

see [Java RMI Example With Security Policy](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javarmi/javarmi.html)

Another [Good RMI Example](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3awE7hAMs9RHoJ%3awww.unf.edu/~sahuja/cnt5505/rmiexample.doc%20&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESh11dv-16ByAGnXh3RFQPkBkgINmf6R0b3xHAteQdLLMTzv_SB2ikhOwO1WJ5MWAXfv5PCuw6I5ve14ps4zuJTvcHAgTWUt7aDzwUe-1BUEWkq94wTlr2wileK3-LkZldbGQQ2w&sig=AHIEtbQtL7Ju_BzGceWNCMF4IiWYZgB-aw&pli=1)

Comment: thanks for your link.
maybe you can give some examples for :

grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\home\\download\\-", "read";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\home\\download\\temp\\*", "read, write, delete";
}

does those block needs some import library?

i'm sorry if my question annoying you.
thank you

Comment: @DinaFrinsimegasari no need to import library for FilePermission, check another example it will help you.

Comment: ok, thx dude..

can i asking to to you again , if i'm difficulting of its?